# TypeError: products.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

Me aparece que la map no es una función como vemos en la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es el siguiente:

```
class ListProduct extends Component {

    render(){
        const {products}=this.props;
        console.log(products);
        return(
            <Table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {

                        products.map(product=>(
                            <tr key={product.id_persona}>
                                <td>{product.Nombre}</td>     
                                <td>
                                    <Button color="info" size="sm">Edit</Button>
                                    <Button color="danger" size="sm">Delete</Button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        ))

                    }
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        )
    }
}
```

Esto es el codigo donde obtengo los datos

```
export default class ProductBox extends Component{

    Url='http://localhost:3005/';
    state={
        products:[],
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch(this.Url)
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(products=>this.setState({products}))
        .catch(e=>console.log(e));

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <h2 className="font-smaller text-center">
                        Cadastro de Productos
                    </h2>
                    <FormProduct/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <h2 className="font-smaller text-center">
                        Lista de Productos
                    </h2>
                    <ListProduct products ={this.state.products}/>
                </div>

        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**lo que el `console.log(products)` me arroja es el siguiente imagen** [image: Esta es la imagen que me lanza navegador algo estoy haciendo mal?]

***la imagen como pueden observar me lanza datos vacio despues me lanza ya con datos de la base de datos***

***Alguien que sepa como puedo solucionar esto estoy siguiendo los pasos de este tutorial si quieren para mas informacion https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJsgUOj73zg***

Comment: Parece ser que props.products no es un array, por lo que no tiene el método `map`

Comment: Alguna sugerencia estoy haciendo como este proyecto youtube.com/watch?v=lJsgUOj73zg

Comment: La sugerencia es que revises lo que trae `products`. Verifica con `console.log` su contenido. Si es que eventualmente viene `null` o `undefined`, haz la validación correspondiente dentro de tu componente `ListProduct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ocurre porque *products* en algun momento no es un array por lo que cuando haces un map no está definido.

El problema viene cuando haces setState en la respuesta de fetch.

```
.then(products => this.setState({products}))
```

*products* no es el array de productos sino un objecto con la cable products, cuando haces setState el estado que tiene el commponente es

```
state = {
  products: {
    products: []
  }
}
```

Puedes solucionarlo deconstrullendo la respuesta en el then añadiendo dos llaves

```
.then(({ products }) => this.setState({ products }))
```